# How can I upgrade my existing AI platform-pipelines deployment to a newer version?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I currently have a deployment of AI platform-pipelines v0.2.5 running. I saw that 8 days ago, a new version v0.5.1 got added to the container registry. There have been a lot of changes, fixes, etc.. between these versions and I would like to update my current deployment. Is there an easy way of doing so, without losing my experiments, pipeline runs, etc..?

Comment: do you think this could work for you? https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/pipelines/upgrade/

Comment: I'm using GCP hosted kubeflow pipelines. In the 'Before you start' section it states:
_Instead of the full Kubeflow deployment, you can use Kubeflow Pipelines Standalone or GCP Hosted ML Pipelines (Alpha), which support different options for upgrading and reinstalling. See the [Kubeflow Pipelines installation options](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/installation/overview/)._
When I check the link out, it only contains info on how to install it, not how to upgrade. It is very much possible, that upgrading is not yet supported, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: You can follow track on this issue and potential solutions here https://issuetracker.google.com/158276137